# Sftp to Mainframe using jsch

Tags: spring-boot, sftp, jsch, mainframe

We have use case where in we need to send file to mainframe. As of now we used ftp to do it and below are commands we used to run from command prompt and there is java ftp library where we can set those properties.

```
ftp> binary
200 Representation type is Image
ftp> quote
Command line to send site unit=tswk lrecl=366 recfm=fb blksize=3660 
200 SITE command was accepted
ftp> put file.txt 'datasetname'
200 Port request OK.
250 Transfer completed successfully.
ftp: 366 bytes sent in 0.30Seconds 1.22Kbytes/sec
```

We can pass the quote command and set the properties like lrec, recfm and blksize from java library as well.

Now we are planning to move it to SFTP and the commands changes as below

```
binary command from ftp changes to ls /+mode=binary
quote command and respective properties from ftp changes to ls/+lrecl=80,blksize=27920,recfm=fb
```

As of now unable to figure out how can we pass those parameters using jsch ( using Spring boot).
Any help here is appreciated.

If Jsch doesnt have that capability, i am ready to use any other open source library.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148105/can-jsch-sftp-support-site-commands-like-lrecl-or-blksize for some examples

Comment: Thanks, somehow that thread didnt show up when i searched, will check it