# Record Level Data truncation on Mainframe server while doing SFTP from spark server

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sftp, jsch, mainframe

Please read this fully.

I am working on sending a csv file via SFTP from spark application developed in scala to the mainframe server. I am using jsch (java secure channel) package version 0.1.53 version to accomplish the SFTP connection from spark server to mainframe server. I am facing issue that on the mainframe server, the csv file gets truncated to **1024 bytes per record line.**

After research, I found that on the mainframe, we have options like using "lrecl" and "recfm" to control the length of each record in the file and the format of that record. But I am unable to integrate these options on scala. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150363/7192927) answer on stackoverflow which was meant for implementation in Java. When I use the same logic on scala, I am getting the below error:

```
EDC5129I No such file or directory., file: /+recfm=fb,lrecl=3000 at
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2198)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2215)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1565)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1526)
```

Scala code block using the jsch library for establishing the SFTP connection and transferring file is as below:

```
session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port)
session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentication","publickey")
session.setConfig("MaxAuthTries",2)
System.out.println("Created SFTP Session")

val sftpSessionConfig: Properties = new Properties()
sftpSessionConfig.put("StrictHostKeyChecking","no")
session.setConfig(sftpSessionConfig)
session.connect() //Connect to session
System.out.println("Connected to SFTP Session")
      
val channel = session.openChannel("sftp")
channel.connect()
val sftpChannel = channel.asInstanceOf[ChannelSftp]
sftpChannel.ls("/+recfm=fb,lrecl=3000") //set lrecl and recfm ---> THROWING ERROR HERE

sftpChannel.put(sourceFile, destinationPath,ChannelSftp.APPEND) //Push file from local to mainframe
```

Is there any way where we can set these options as the configuration in my scala code using the jsch library? I also tried using the spring-ml's spark-sftp package. But this package also has the problem of data truncation on the mainframe server.

Please help as this issue has become very critical blocker to my project.

**EDIT: Updated question with scala code block**

Comment: I have tested the connection to SFTP from my spark server using the scala code, the connection is getting established correctly and I am even able to push the file. Only issue is every record line gets truncated which I need to fix..  I haven't tried Java as our project is purely developed on scala..

Comment: The mainframe is running z/OS, I suppose. Have you considered to send the file to the UNIX file system on z/OS?

Comment: Seems to me that the problem is not related to Spark. For debugging purposes I would try to write a small program purely in Scala (without Spark) to check what happens

Comment: @werner while trying this on my local system without the spark server, I get the same issue.  Issue is mainframe server has default length of record per line (lrecl) defined.  We need to increase the lrecl value  in our scala code so that the row level truncation does not occur while writing file on mainframe using sftp .

Comment: Is the z/OS side running Dovetail's sftp server?  I believe the `ls` extensions are specific to their product.

Comment: @cschneid Good question! I was assuming it is, since the OP posted code which shows `lrecl=...,recfm=...`. And, I believe only Dovetail's sftp does support MVS data sets. Since he reported record tuncation because of LRECL=1024, I was again assuming it is Dovetail's sftp they are using.

Comment: Again, the question: Have you considered sending the CSV to the z/OS UNIX System Service's file system. No problems with things like `LRECL`, `RECFM`, or `SPACE`. It is easy to access the UNIX file from programs running on z/OS, or if needed, it is easy to copy it over to an MVS data set with z/OS utilities.

Comment: I think it is not Dovetail's sftp server which is why ls commands are failing. I found a way to send mainframe commands from our scala code using the ChannelExec class, but even that was sending `No file or directory found exception`. I am not much aware of the mainframe specification as my task was to push csv file to the server data specified..

Comment: For now, we did a workaround to create a file with the required LRECL, RECFM specification on the mainframe server and I used jsch library's `ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE` feature from the scala code while pushing the csv file. This worked. But still it is a hack, I need solution to use the jsch library using scala.

Comment: I suggest you talk to your client and ask them what STFP server they're running. Then ask them talk to the vendor of said product and ask for help specifying the LRECL, RECFM parameters, if supported at all.  All we seem to be able to talk about here is speculation without that knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

From this presentation [Dovetail SFTP Webinar](https://dovetail.com/docs/sftp/sftp-webinar.pdf) on slide 21:

```
ls /+recfm=fb,lrecl=80
```

it seems to me there is one '/' too many in your code.

From the error message, I think the SFTP server has the current path in the UNIX file system. You do not set the data set high level qualifier (HLQ) for the data set, do you? I can't see it in the code. Again from the above presentation, do a `cd` before the `ls`:

```
cd //your-hlq-of-choice
```

This will do two things:

1. Change the current working directory to the MVS data set side.
2. Set the HLQ to be used.

Sorry I cannot test myself; I do not know scala.

Comment: I am still getting EDC5129I No such file or directory., file: /+recfm=fb,lrecl=3000
2: EDC5129I No such file or directory., file: /+recfm=fb,lrecl=3000
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2198)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2215)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1565)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1526)

I will update my question with the code that we are using to specify these options.

Comment: Updated my question with scala code block. Please have a look and help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, what SFTP server is running on z/OS?  If it is the one provided with z/OS (not Dovetail) the command you are executing isn't supported and you will receive a message like `Can't ls: "/+recfm=fb,lrecl=80" not found`.  Which would be valid because that is not valid file.  Everything to the right of the `/` would be considered part of the filename.

I converted your code to Java as I'm not familiar with Scala and didn't have time to learn it.  Here was my code sample I used.

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Vector;

class sftptest {
  static public void main(String[] args) {

    String username = "ibmuser";
    String host = "localhost";
    int port = 10022;              // Note, my z/OS is running in a docker container so I map 10022 to 22
    JSch jsch = new JSch(); 
    String sourceFile = "/";
    String destinationPath ="/";
    String privateKey = "myPrivateKey";


    try {
      jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);                   //add private key path and file
      com.jcraft.jsch.Session session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
      session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentication","password");
      session.setConfig("MaxAuthTries", "2");
      System.out.println("Created SFTP Session");

      Properties sftpSessionConfig = new Properties();
      sftpSessionConfig.put("StrictHostKeyChecking","no");
      session.setConfig(sftpSessionConfig);
      session.connect(); //Connect to session
      System.out.println("Connected to SFTP Session");
      
      com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp channel = (com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
      channel.connect();
      // com.jcraft.jsch.Channel sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
      //    channel.ls("/+recfm=fb,lrecl=3000"); //set lrecl and recfm ---> THROWING ERROR HERE
      //    channel.ls("/"); //set lrecl and recfm ---> THROWING ERROR HERE
      Vector filelist = channel.ls("/");
      for(int i=0; i<filelist.size();i++){
          System.out.println(filelist.get(i).toString());
      }


    //  channel.put(sourceFile, destinationPath, com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.APPEND);  //Push file from local to mainframe
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception "+e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

For my case I did use an ssh key and not a password.  The output with your `ls` method is:

```
Created SFTP Session
Connected to SFTP Session
Exception No such file
```

dropping the `+` and everything to the right you get:

```
Created SFTP Session
Connected to SFTP Session
drwxr-xr-x    2 OMVSKERN SYS1         8192 May 13 01:18 .
drwxr-xr-x    7 OMVSKERN SYS1         8192 May 13 01:18 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 OMVSKERN SYS1            0 May 13 01:18 file 1
-rw-r--r--    1 OMVSKERN SYS1            0 May 13 01:18 file 2
```

The main issue is that the z/OS appears to not support the syntax you are using which is provided by a specific SFTP implementation by Dovetail.

If you do not have Dovetail I recommend that since you are sending CSV files that are generally variable in length that you send them as a USS file so that the lines will be properly translated and will be of variable length.  Transfer them to USS (regular Unix on z/OS) and then copy them to an MVS file that has a RECFM of VB.  Assuming the file is already allocated you could do a `cp myuploadedFile.csv "//'MY.MVS.FILE'"`